# htaccess redirect for exact one domain name

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My web portal is moved in to another location. so i want to redirect my domain name in to another location

```
 RewriteRule .* http://check.site.local%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newcheckcheck.site.local$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This working perfectly for me. But There is some web services are present in my old place. That not changed

```
 http://check.site.local/web_services/index.php
```

By using above rule this also changed as

```
 http://newcheck.site.local/web_services/index.php
```

if any thing can do for replacing only exact domain name comes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this rule **before other rules**:

```
# ignore rest of the rules if URI starts with /web_services/
RewriteRule ^web_services/ - [L,NC]
```